# CGContextDrawRadialGradient is slower on ipad 3 vs ipad 2

Tags: ios, ipad, gradient

I am using the time profiler tool and am comparing latency.

I have exactly the same code, and at some point in one of my view's drawRect, I call CGContextDrawRadialGradient()

In the IPad 2, it takes 100 ms
In the IPad 3, it takes 310 ms

Anyone have any idea why and how I can speed up the performance of the ipad3

Comment: The main reason why is that you have 4 times as many pixels on the iPad 3.  Is this something you can do in the background?

Comment: I have tried doing it in the background but still get the same overall time of 310+ms in drawRect